# Can't call xlsxwriter

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

This is my first time trying to create excel files with python. I installed xlsxwriter successfully and when I run just:

```
import xlsxwriter
```

I do not get any errors. But when I try to make a workbook

```
import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.workbook("result.xlsx")
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

on the second line. I'm not sure why it can't call xlsxwriter though. 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You need `xlsxwriter.Workbook`. Python is case-sensitive

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a mistake in calling `workbook`

`workbook   = xlsxwriter.Workbook('filename.xlsx')`

Please check the `Workbook` word.

Comment: Thanks! That worked! The tutorial I was using made a typo.